# how to select all from table and its matches from another?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables:

TblAchievements>> [ID, AchName]

TblUsersAchievements>> [UserID, AchID]

i need the results to be like this (assuming that there are 4 achievements and the user 1 have achieved 1 and 2:

```
 ID     AchName     UserID     AchID
 1      first         1         1
 2      second        1         2
 3      third        NULL      NULL
 4      fourth       NULL      NULL
```

i tried some thing like this:

```
 SELECT 
   tblacheivements.id,
   tblacheivements.achname,
   tbluserachievements.uid,
   tbluserachievements.achid
 FROM
   tbluserachievements
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblacheivements ON (tbluserachievements.achid = tblacheivements.id)
 WHERE
   tbluserachievements.uid = 1 OR 
   tbluserachievements.uid IS NULL
```

it gets the correct result but when i change the user the results are wrong.

Comment: Please spend some more time on this question - it's very confusing. I think there are maybe too many commas in this string and such. `ID, AchName, UserID, AchID 1,first,1,1 2,second,1,2 3,third,NULL,NULL 4,fourth,NULL,NULL`

Comment: Your where clause makes no sense, it essentially will get all rows.

Comment: and this is what i want, i want to view all the achievments and what ever the user 1 achieved from them.

Comment: Example data would be good. As it stands, I have no idea what you want. Try saying in plain English what data you want, especially since given your schema more than one user may have any given achievement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to list out all achievements a particular user has or doesn't have. To filter on the `UserID`, but still retain each achievement row in the result-set, you have to include the `UserID` selection in the outer-join condition (putting it in the `WHERE` clause will only select rows where the user achieved the achievement since `WHERE` is evaluated after `FROM` / `JOIN`.)

Try this solution:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      tblachievements a
LEFT JOIN tbluserachievements b ON a.id = b.achid AND b.uid = 1
```

---

**Extra:**

Depending on your application requirements, perhaps it may be better to simply have a boolean value indicating whether the user has achieved it or not (`1` if they did, `0` if not):

```
SELECT    a.*, b.achid IS NOT NULL AS achieved
FROM      tblachievements a
LEFT JOIN tbluserachievements b ON a.id = b.achid AND b.uid = 1
```

Which would produce:

```
 id     achname     achieved
 ---------------------------
 1      first       1     
 2      second      1     
 3      third       0   
 4      fourth      0
```